# how can I do a full_text_search, using sequel ORM, with 3 parameters?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

This is for Jeremy! It may not be possible as I would like to pass 3 parameters to a full text search but it is designed to take only one. Here is the code:

```
experience_search_term = params[:search_term] 
candidates.full_text_search(:experience, experience_search_term).to_a.to_json
```

works fine, but

```
candidates.where(:city => params['city'], :industry => params['industry']).full_text_search(:experience  => params['search_term']).to_a.to_json
```

does not and nor does this hack:

```
dataset = candidates.where(:city => params['city'], :industry => params['industry'])
dataset.full_text_search(:experience  => params['search_term']).to_a.to_json
```

Is there a way to do this? All help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use 2 arguments instead of a single hash, just as in your first example:

```
dataset = candidates.where(:city => params['city'], :industry => params['industry'])
dataset.full_text_search(:experience, params['search_term']).to_a.to_json
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you Jeremy. That looks different. i will give it a shot and come back tomorrow.

Comment: awesome Jeremy, many thanks. Last time we discussed full_text_search you said you would consider making it possible to do it with more than one word, a phrase for example. Any further thoughts on that?

Comment: PostgreSQL already supports that. You just need to single quote the phrase in the search term: `dataset.full_text_search(:experience, "'multiple words here'").to_a.to_json`

Comment: thank you! Got to figure out how to pass the parameter encased in single quotes.